# MessageWebSocket ConnectAsync times out when using TLS 1.2 and self signed certificates

Tags: ssl, websocket, timeout, self, signed

I'm trying to send some bytes via a Socket connection to a server using TLS 1.2 and self signed certificates in an UWP app.

I'm trying with the code below, but I get an error: WinRT information: The operation timed out when the line webSocket.ConnectAsync is executed.

I can see with Wireshark that TLS handshake is initiated to the correct ip address and port number.

```
private static MessageWebSocket messageWebSocket;
    private static DataWriter messageWriter;

    public static async Task<bool> SocketControl()
    {
        try
        {
            //creates a new MessageWebSocket and connects to WebSocket server and sends data to server

            //Make a local copy
            MessageWebSocket webSocket = messageWebSocket;

            //Have we connected yet?
            if (webSocket == null)
            {
                Uri myUri = new Uri("wss://192.168.0.135:51200");
                webSocket = new MessageWebSocket();
                webSocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Binary;
                webSocket.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;
                webSocket.Closed += Closed;
                webSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
                webSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);

                await webSocket.ConnectAsync(myUri); // Times out here, Output=WinRT information: The operation timed out
                messageWebSocket = webSocket;
                messageWriter = new DataWriter(webSocket.OutputStream);
            }

            messageWriter.WriteBytes(new byte[] {0, 1});
            await messageWriter.StoreAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String.Format("There is an error in connection");
        }
        return true;
    }


    //Sends the data
    private static void MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader())
            {
                //reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                //string read = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                //var read = reader.ReadBytes();// .ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                var read = reader.ReadByte();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String.Format("There is an error sending the data");
        }
    }


    // Close connection
    private static void Closed(IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageWebSocket webSocket = Interlocked.Exchange(ref messageWebSocket, null);
        if (webSocket != null)
        {
            webSocket.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I do have a sample script in Python which works fine without any problems, I just want to do the same in c#

Part of the Python script looks like this:

```
def main():
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
sock.settimeout(10.0)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.check_hostname = False
#accept self-signed certificate
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

conn = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=KLF200_ADDRESS)

try:
    conn.connect((KLF200_ADDRESS, PORT))
    process_connection(conn)
except BaseException as e:
    raise(e)
finally:
    conn.close()

main()
```

Comment: You are confusing plain sockets (or plain sockets with TLS) with Websockets - which sound similar but are different and incompatible things. Your python client is using plain (TLS) sockets while your c# client  is doing WebSockets.

Comment: Steffen, that could explain quite a lot.
So instead of the MessageWebSocket, what should I then use, maybe Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener?

Comment: I have no experience with c# myself but a simple search for [c# socket](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+socket) seems to provide the relevant information.